# ActionScript 3: Enter frame with movieclip and play a sound just once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm a beginner in as3 and now I'm working on a little game where you can explore different rooms with different events. Every single room is in a movieclip and now I want to play a single sound in a few rooms, but this sound should just played once in the whole game.

I've tryed to insert the sound in the main-timeline, where the certain room is in it, with a "synchronization" as "start" and no repeats, but this didn't work. So the sound is playing everytime you go in this room and that's annoying.

What can I do?

Comment: You need persistent data that's not stored on the timeline. Then when you enter that frame, you check that data, and if it says the sound was already played, you skip starting the sound.

Comment: Sounds great and traceable, but how can I do that?

Comment: I hate to be the one to say it, but coding on the timeline is not ideal for anything more complex than a slideshow presentation.  (code using classes... look here:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix--active-5789).  The other option is to not put you rooms on different frames... add and change them programatically so that you are always on frame 1 of the main timeline.

Comment: in the first frame add a variable to store whether the sounds has been played already or not. When the point is reached where it should play, check the value, if it is first time visit, then play the music and change the value of the variable. So when you visit that point again you will know it already played.

Comment: Thank you, RST, I'll try to work with that.